# Mouse event in DrawingArea with PyGtk

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I want to get the X and Y coordinates when I click on a DrawingArea. I was looking for some examples and I found a code like the following

```
import gtk

class Ventana(gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Ventana, self).__init__()

        self.set_title('Test')
        self.set_size_request(800, 600)
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)

        self.drawing_area = gtk.DrawingArea()
        self.drawing_area.set_size_request(780, 500)
        self.drawing_area.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.color_parse('white'))
        self.drawing_area.connect('button-press-event', self.on_drawing_area_button_press)

        fixed = gtk.Fixed()
        fixed.put(self.drawing_area, 10, 10)

        self.add(fixed)

        self.show_all()

    def on_drawing_area_button_press(self, widget, event):
        print event.x, ' ', event.y


def main():
    Ventana()
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run it, the window appears and the DrawingArea with the white background, but when I click on it, it doesn't print the values of `event.x` and `event.y` and there are no error messages.

Can anyone tell me what is the correct way to do that?

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drawing area needs to be setup with event masks for the events you want to connect to it.

```
self.drawing_area.set_events(gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
```

See: http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-EventHandling.html
(which also has a good example at the bottom of the page)