# How to get cursor position on hover in GTK-rs drawing area?

Tags: rust, gtk, drawingarea

I am working on a GTK-rs application in Rust that includes a drawing area. I am trying to print the position of the cursor to the command line whenever the user hovers over the drawing area. I have tried using the motion notify event with a callback function that retrieves the x and y coordinates of the event using the position() method, and then prints them to the console using println!(). However, when I run the application and hover over the drawing area, nothing is printed to the console.

Here is the Rust code I am using:

```
use cairo::{ImageSurface, Context, Format};
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Builder, Window, DrawingArea};

fn main() {
    if let Err(err) = gtk::init() {
        println!("Failed to initialize GTK: {}", err);
        return;
    }

    let glade_src = include_str!("interface.ui");
    let builder = Builder::from_string(glade_src);

    let window: Window = builder.object("main").unwrap();
    let drawing: DrawingArea = builder.object("canvas").unwrap();    
    
    let surface = ImageSurface::create(Format::ARgb32, 600, 700).unwrap();
    drawing.connect_draw(move |_,cr| {
        let surface_ctx = Context::new(&surface).unwrap();
        surface_ctx.set_source_rgb(1.0,1.0,1.0);
        surface_ctx.paint().expect("unable to paint surface_ctx");

        cr.set_source_surface(&surface, 0.0, 0.0).expect("unable to set source surface");
        cr.paint().expect("unable to paint context");
        Inhibit(false)
    });
    
    drawing.connect_motion_notify_event(|_widget, event| {
        let x = event.position().0;
        let y = event.position().1;
        println!("Mouse click position: ({}, {})", x, y);
        Inhibit(false)
    });

    window.show_all();

    gtk::main();
}
```

Here's the interface.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.38.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="main">
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkPaned">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">True</property>
        <property name="position">400</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkDrawingArea" id="canvas">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">False</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="resize">False</property>
            <property name="shrink">True</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">A scaled down version
 of the interface.ui</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="resize">True</property>
            <property name="shrink">True</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

I have tried using the `button_press_event` signal, the `motion_notify_event`, and `drawing.grab_focus()` to capture mouse events, but none of these methods have worked for me.

I expected that when I hovered over the drawing area, my program would print the position of the cursor to the console. However, nothing is being printed when I hover over the drawing area.

Any suggestions on how to make this work or what I am missing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit of research and came across [this Python answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23952405/16775594) to a similar problem, which shows that you need to set up the `DrawingArea` in order for it to receive events. So in your code, you would use `gdk` to set up the `POINTER_MOTION_MASK`, like so:

```rust
drawing.set_events(gdk::EventMask::POINTER_MOTION_MASK);
```

So your complete program will look like this:

```rust
use gtk::cairo::{ImageSurface, Context, Format};
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Builder, Window, DrawingArea};
use gdk;

fn main() {
    if let Err(err) = gtk::init() {
        println!("Failed to initialize GTK: {}", err);
        return;
    }

    let glade_src = include_str!("interface.ui");
    let builder = Builder::from_string(glade_src);

    let window: Window = builder.object("main").unwrap();
    let drawing: DrawingArea = builder.object("canvas").unwrap();    
    
    let surface = ImageSurface::create(Format::ARgb32, 600, 700).unwrap();
    drawing.connect_draw(move |_,cr| {
        let surface_ctx = Context::new(&surface).unwrap();
        surface_ctx.set_source_rgb(1.0,1.0,1.0);
        surface_ctx.paint().expect("unable to paint surface_ctx");

        cr.set_source_surface(&surface, 0.0, 0.0).expect("unable to set source surface");
        cr.paint().expect("unable to paint context");
        Inhibit(false)
    });
    drawing.set_events(gdk::EventMask::POINTER_MOTION_MASK);
    drawing.connect_motion_notify_event(|_widget, event| {
        let x = event.position().0;
        let y = event.position().1;
        println!("Mouse click position: ({}, {})", x, y);
        Inhibit(false)
    });

    window.show_all();

    gtk::main();
}
```

The program will output the cursor position when the mouse moves over the drawing area, as intended.